# Building angular app with multiple version dependencies

Tags: angularjs

I have a huge angular app , it has many modules which further have smaller modules. Question is when my smallest module upgrades do i have to upgrade every of its parent modules ? or can i run some parent modules with latest version some with the older version ? If i can run multiple version of the smallest module , how to do it ?

So, `angular.module('bigModuleA',['smallModule_version1']), angular.module('bigModuleB',['smallModule_version2'])` , this should be possible technically , but not sure if a good way to do it.

Comment: Is there any reason you *want* to do this? And if so, have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: [This article](http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/) may help you. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to do this because i need to update my application bit by bit , not wait for all the bigModules to support the new version of small module and then release the application. It does work , but all kinds of weird stuff happens when you go for building via Browserify etc.

Comment: Do all of your tests still pass? What is *"weird stuff"*? Could you give some concrete examples?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had the following ModuleA injects ModC(Ver1) , ModuleB injects ModC(Ver2). It works if i don't do the bundling and write it in normal Angularjs. But after bundling and refactoring into commonjs format which ever version of ModC was required last comes into play into both ModuleA and ModuleB. (I have not written test still , just doing a POC)